# How to compare two different tables with different number of entries and not same column

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to compare two tables to see which users work for a certain company.  The two tables have different number of entries, therefore, are not listed in the same position.  Is there a way to compare the two tables by e-mail address?

Comment: Can you provide table definitions and query statements you have already tried?

Comment: Agreed with @WEI_DBA.  Some sample records and an expected output would certainly help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no sample data or table names, I will invent it as an example.

```
   CREATE TABLE Table1
   (
     Value1 INT
     , Email VARCHAR(255)
   )

   INSERT INTO Table1 (Value1,Email)
   VALUES (1,'email@test.com')
     , (2,'email2@test2.com')


    CREATE TABLE Table2
    (
      Value1 INT
      , Email VARCHAR(255)
    )

    INSERT INTO Table2 (Value1,Email)
    VALUES (3,'email3@test.com')
        , (2,'email2@test2.com')
        , (100,'email@test.com')
```

If you want to select all from table 1 and see where table2 values have matching emails.

```
    SELECT t1.Value1 as Tab1Value, t2.Value1 AS Tab2Value, t1.Email, t2.Email  
    FROM Table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
           ON t1.Email = t2.Email
```

If you want to see all values from Table2 and see all records from table1 where there is a matching email, do this;

```
    SELECT t1.Value1 as Tab1Value, t2.Value1 AS Tab2Value, t1.Email, t2.Email  
    FROM Table2 t2
        LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
            ON t1.Email = t2.Email
```